# How can I get JSON response if I pass .json after URL in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am stucked at one point in which I need to get JSON response if I pass .json behind the URL as below Example:

```
http://www.urlabc.com/home.json
```

The same way I need to get XML data like,

```
http://www.urlabc.com/home.xml
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it by using `$_SERVER`

```
 $actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
```

This will return you actual path i.e `http://www.urlabc.com/home.json`

ANd by using `pathinfo` You get the extension of url as

```
echo $ext = pathinfo($actual_link, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if($ext=="json")
{
  // json code
}

if($ext=="xml")
{
  // xml code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I think you should use pass "json" as query parameter
e.g.[http://www.example.com?type=json]
```

Also use Codeigniter Rest Server [Click here](https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver)